# Mix just wiped my entire project directory!

Tags: mix

Turns out if you try to create a new project using an existing directory, Mix wipes the directory first.

It's just lost me my last months DAPP work!

I ran into troubles when mix stopped acknowledging the 'Rebuild Scenario' buttons and failed to show 'expand transaction' buttons.  Restarting and reloading the scenario failed to restore functionality.  New projects could create fine but even the default Sample project fails to set()

Comment: are you asking a question ?

Comment: If you believe it's a mix bug, let's report it on the github issue tracker please.

Comment: Yes I reported it on github with the reproduction instructions.